# Ember access controller from an array of functions in this controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scope

I am struggling with accessing an object: in controller I have an array of functions, function1 receives an object, how can I access this object from this controller of current template?

Scope of "this" inside function1 is functionsArray, and, consequently, it has only function1 and function2 methods, so it is not possible to set a controller variable like this in function1: this.set('data', data_to_pass); - it says "this.set is not a function".

I receive data_to_pass from another component, so one solution is to pass this controller to the component and then pass it back in function1, but that would be a bad decision from performance point of view.

```js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

 t: [], // not visible inside functionsArray

 functionsArray: {
    
    function1(data_to_pass) {
      
      // how would I pass data_to_pass to this controller or template here?
      this.set('data', data_to_pass); // doesn't work, scope of "this" is functionsArray
      console.log('data' + data_to_pass.fullName);
    },

    function2() {
      
    },

 }

});
```

Comment: First `functionsArray` is an object. not an array. But how do you call this functions? The `this` context in JS is determinated by the caller. So if you don't provide the `this` context when you call the function there is not way to access the controller. Why don't you declare the functions on the controller directly?

Comment: Based on what you posted I think the way you setup your controller and how you're trying to use a component is fundamentally flawed.  Can you provide a little more background on what you're trying to do at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t: [], // not visible inside functionsArray

functionsArray: Ember.Object.create({

  function1: function(data_to_pass) {

  // how would I pass data_to_pass to this controller or template here?
  this.set('data', data_to_pass); // doesn't work, scope of "this" is functionsArray
  alert(this.get('data'));
  },

  function2: function() {

  },

}),

actions: {
   press: function() {
       this.functionsArray.function1('works!');
   }
},


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <button {{action "press"}}>Press here</button>
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.